# Samsung Galaxy s3 emulator settings

Tags: android, android-emulator, galaxy, samsung-mobile

Can anyone with galaxy s3 access confirm the below emulator settings for Galaxy s3?

Target: Google APIs - API Level 15
Skin: Built-in WXGA720

- Hardware Back/Home: yes
- Abstracted LCD density: 320
- Keyboard lid support: no
- Max VM application heap size: 48
- Device ram size: 1024

Comment: If you want some settings for other devices check this: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/emulator-settings-for-each-android-density/

Comment: @Netverse - I am trying to use the Galaxy S2 skin, does your avd display the contents at the same size as on the device? I can't get this to work on the S2 skin.

Comment: @Neil Yes with the avd I have created (above config), it exactly displays the content at the same size as that on device.

Comment: As for screen size, set it to 720 x 1280, instead of WXGA720

Comment: The max VM heap size has been extracted from an actual device or just guessing? I am having OutOfMemory problems on SGS3 without reaching 48 Mbytes by far on emulator (maximum peak less than 42Mb).

And the abstracted LCD density is the one that is used by the actual device? The real density seems to be about 306 or so...

Comment: Samsung offers test environements. See http://developer.samsung.com/remoteTestLab.do

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had to set the device ram to 512 in emulator. Above configs were the best possible match I could get after comparing with the real Galaxy S3 device.

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S3 has 1024MB RAM see specification http://www.phonearena.com/phones/Samsung-Galaxy-S-III_id6330, any specific reason why you have set it to 512 in emulator.

Comment: Yes, I know actual device has 1 GB ram. However on my system setting 1 gb ram for emulator, was crashing it.

Comment: the s3 has 2gb of ram, my mom has one and we used a app that measures the amount of ram in the device.

Comment: @ravenmyers The S3 has 1GB of physical memory. The 2GB your app measured was probably [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

Answer (score 0):

It work for me with 768MB RAM. On Windows, emulating RAM greater than 768MB may fail depending on the system load.