# Android: AVD-Settings for Galaxy S3-Like AVD

Tags: android, device, android-virtual-device, galaxy, samsung-mobile

I need help with the AVD-Settings for my new Virtual Device.

I need the settings for an AVD that has the same size like the new Samsung Galaxy S3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Samsung Galaxy s3 emulator settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804619/samsung-galaxy-s3-emulator-settings)

Comment: Instructions for Samsung Emulators for Android Studio and Eclipse are located here:

Using Samsung Emulator Skins for Android Application Development http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000095

The skins can be downloaded here:
http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/list.do?pi=1&ps=50&pb=Y&ct=CT350000&sc=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just saw a detailed description here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2365104 :

- Name: Samsung_Galaxy_S3_IceCream
- Target: Android 4.0 (Api level 14)
- SDCard: 16 Gb
- Skin: WVGA800
- Hardware:

  - **Size 4.8 inches (~65.9% screen-to-body ratio)**
  - **Resolution   720 x 1280 pixels (~306 ppi pixel density)**
  - **Device Ram Size: 1024**
  - Hardware Back/Home keys: yes
  - Abstracted LDC density: 320
  - Keyboard lid support: no
  - Max VM application heap size: 48
  - Accelerometer: yes
  - Audio Playback support: yes
  - Audio recording support: yes
  - Battery support: yes
  - GPS support: yes
  - Orientation support: yes
  - Magnetic Field support: yes (I know GSM arena does not state it has one but you can get magnetic iron detection working when using apps such as Smart Tools and it is reported in benchmarking apps like Quadrant).
  - Proximity support: yes (Once more, GSM arena does not state it but Quadrant Benchmark reports the existance of CM36651 Proximity Sensor)
  - LCD Color depth: 32 (In reality, the S3 has 16M color which is 24 bits)
  - LCD Pixel height: 1280
  - LCD Pixel width: 720
  - SD Card Support: yes
  - Touch screen type: multi-touch
  - Track-ball support: no

Answer (score 33):

I created one based of the stats that GSM arena states (http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9300_galaxy_s_iii-4238.php).

So, for a completely stock device, I used the following specs:

- Name: Samsung_Galaxy_S3_IceCream
- Target: Android 4.0 (Api level 14)
- SDCard: 16 Gb
- Skin: WVGA800
- Hardware

  - Device Ram Size: 1024 MB
  - Hardware Back/Home keys: yes
  - Abstracted LDC density: 320
  - Keyboard lid support: no
  - Max VM application heap size: 48 MiB
  - Accelerometer: yes
  - Audio Playback support: yes
  - Audio recording support: yes
  - Battery support: yes
  - GPS support: yes
  - Orientation support: yes
  - Magnetic Field support: yes (I know GSM arena does not state it has one but you can get magnetic iron detection working when using apps such as Smart Tools and it is reported in benchmarking apps like Quadrant).
  - Proximity support: yes (Once more, GSM arena does not state it but Quadrant Benchmark reports the existance of CM36651 Proximity Sensor)
  - LCD Color depth: 32 (In reality, the S3 has 16M color which is 24 bits)
  - LCD Pixel height: 1280
  - LCD Pixel width: 720
  - SD Card Support: yes
  - Touch screen type: multi-touch
  - Track-ball support: no

For one with update to JellyBean, all values are the same except as follows:
 - Name: Samsung_Galaxy_S3_JellyBean
 - Target: Android 4.1 (Api level 15)

When starting the AVD, If you want to scale to the original size, the real screen size is 4.8 inches with a density of 306 px/inch.

Answer (score 24):

Some of these settings have to be set up on the "Device Definitions" tab for the newer SDK.

> Screen Size (in): 4.8
>   Resolution (px): 720  x   1280
>   Sensors: Accelerometer, Gyroscope, GPS, Proximity Sensor
>   Cameras: Front, Back
>   Input: Keyboard (Checked), No Nav
>   RAM: 1024 MiB
>   Size: Normal
>   Screen Ratio: [long](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=478)
>   Density: [xhdpi](http://blog.blundellapps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/)
>   Buttons: Hardware

When you try to start the virtual device it should ask you for the real DPI in the "Launch Options" dialog window.

> Screen Size (in): 4.8
>   Monitor dpi: 306
>   Scale: 1.00

Answer (score 9):

Try using this settings

- Target: Google APIs
- API Level 15
- Skin: WXGA720

Hardware properties

- Hardware Back/Home: yes
- Abstracted LCD density: 320
- Keyboard lid support: no
- Max VM application heap size: 48
- Device ram size: 512

It should be pretty accurate.