# How can I configure the Android emulator to simulate the Galaxy 3

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, galaxy

I've seen a similar question for the Nexus, but my app crashes on the Galaxy 3 only.. anybody knows the correct parameters for this?

Comment: Explain you error please. If you have logs, post it.

Comment: @QuentinT.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999204/android-gridview-crashes-on-galaxy-3

Comment: I entered the same parameters as mentioned above, but when I click the button create AVD it doesn't work, for API level greater than 12, Can you guide me?

Answer (score 1):

This could be kinda difficult. In your `AVD Manager` are some options wich can be adjusted.
But otherwise as a good developer you need some devices to test on, or you got some users with some devices.

As the S3 has Samsung's UI (Touchwiz afaik) this "could" cause your probleme, but anyway you can not create an emulator with Touchwiz.

See a smiliar problem: [Samsung Galaxy s3 emulator settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804619/samsung-galaxy-s3-emulator-settings)