# android gridview crashes on Galaxy 3

Tags: android, gridview, galaxy

Ok, I think I have a real question for a change.
I implemented a gridView in Android, following step by step the instructions in the Android Developers page, http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html
I changed it so that when clicking on a view, the bitmap will be returned. This all works great on advanced phones like Galxy Note and Galaxy S2, and on less advanced ones like Galaxy ace and even some crappy htc from 2 years ago. But for some reason, it crashes on galaxy 3 with ICS due to OutOfMemory issues. When using about half of the images on the gridview, it does work (albeit a bit slowly). Does this make any sense to anyone?

This is my implementation of ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private int mWidth;
private int mHeight;

public ImageAdapter(Context c, int width, int height) {
    mContext = c;
    mWidth = width;
    mHeight = height;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(mWidth, mHeight));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.third_world , R.drawable.annoyinggirl,
        R.drawable.asianfather, R.drawable.awkawespeng,
        R.drawable.awkpeng, R.drawable.blankdad,
        R.drawable.collegesenior, R.drawable.courage,
        R.drawable.frog, R.drawable.frynotsure,
        R.drawable.goodguygreg, R.drawable.scumbag,
        R.drawable.raptor,R.drawable.keano,
        R.drawable.successkid, R.drawable.wonka,
        R.drawable.braceyourselves, R.drawable.onedoesnotsimply,
        R.drawable.firstworldproblem, R.drawable.amitheonlyone,
        R.drawable.badluckbrian, R.drawable.interestingman,
        R.drawable.toodamnhigh, R.drawable.def    
};
```

}

This is the calling function from my main:

```
  private void changeToTemplateView(){
    setContentView(R.layout.templates);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(context, (int)(dstWidth * 1.4), (int)(dstHeight * 1.4)));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            Options opts = new Options();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), (int) parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position), opts);

            //do stuff with bitmap          
        }
    });
}
```

And this is the xml for the gridview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
```

/>

If anyone has any idea what I might be doing wrong here, I will be forever grateful

EDIT: Before the crash, I get an error in the log: "FimgApiStretch:stretch failed". Also, the scrolling in the gridview doesn't work. This is regardless of the fact that even if there aren't enough thumbnails to cause a scroll, the app will still crash

Comment: can you provide the logcat messages?

Comment: @Muhannad only tomorrow, I don't own a Galaxy s3 and will not have access to one today. Will it be any help if I show the actual gridview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to replace fill_parent with match_parent because according to my information the attribute value fill_parent is deprecated on android 2.2 and above 
hope this would help

You can see this link http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html 
I hope this will help you

Comment: I faced a broblem in Galaxy S3 I think it is the same , and it is related to decoding bitmaps , it will cause OutOfMemoryError , so if you can provide the logcat error information asap

Comment: this is taken from Google play and is a problem that appears for many other users, I assume it's the same one as the Galaxy 3's problem
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:494)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:370)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:715)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1720)

Comment: see the link above and tell us if you get any benefit

Comment: I posted the solution below. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

AS for the question "why the hell is it crashing on galaxy 3 and not on inferior phones", the answer is "I have no clue". But, turns out I have been misusing the gridview. It is a bad idea to use the same image both for the thumbnail and for the whole image. What I did (which might be nothing more than a workaround, but it works) is to use 2 sets of images, small one and full size ines. This is done like this

For setting the thumbnails:

```
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.third_world__small , R.drawable.annoyinggirl__small,
        R.drawable.asianfather__small, R.drawable.awkawespeng__small,
        R.drawable.awkpeng__small, R.drawable.blankdad__small,
        R.drawable.collegesenior__small, R.drawable.courage__small,
        R.drawable.frog__small, R.drawable.frynotsure__small,
        R.drawable.goodguygreg__small, R.drawable.scumbag__small,
        R.drawable.raptor__small,R.drawable.keano__small,
        R.drawable.successkid__small, R.drawable.wonka__small,
        R.drawable.braceyourselves__small, R.drawable.onedoesnotsimply__small,
        R.drawable.firstworldproblem__small, R.drawable.amitheonlyone__small,
        R.drawable.badluckbrian__small, R.drawable.interestingman__small,
        R.drawable.toodamnhigh__small, R.drawable.def__small    
};

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //clearAllResources();
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(mWidth, mHeight));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}
```

Then, create another array:

```
private Map<Integer, Integer> mThumbIdToFullSizeId = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
public ImageAdapter(Context c, int width, int height) {
    mContext = c;
    mWidth = width;
    mHeight = height;
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.third_world__small, R.drawable.third_world);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.annoyinggirl__small,R.drawable.annoyinggirl);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.asianfather__small, R.drawable.asianfather);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.awkawespeng__small, R.drawable.awkawespeng);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.awkpeng__small, R.drawable.awkpeng);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.blankdad__small, R.drawable.blankdad);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.collegesenior__small, R.drawable.collegesenior);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.courage__small, R.drawable.courage);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.frog__small, R.drawable.frog);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.frynotsure__small, R.drawable.frynotsure);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.goodguygreg__small, R.drawable.goodguygreg);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.scumbag__small, R.drawable.scumbag);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.raptor__small, R.drawable.raptor);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.keano__small, R.drawable.keano);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.successkid__small, R.drawable.successkid);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.wonka__small, R.drawable.wonka);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.braceyourselves__small, R.drawable.braceyourselves);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.onedoesnotsimply__small, R.drawable.onedoesnotsimply);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.firstworldproblem__small, R.drawable.firstworldproblem);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.amitheonlyone__small, R.drawable.amitheonlyone);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.badluckbrian__small, R.drawable.badluckbrian);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.interestingman__small, R.drawable.interestingman);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.toodamnhigh__small, R.drawable.toodamnhigh);
    mThumbIdToFullSizeId.put(R.drawable.def__small, R.drawable.def);
}
```

Then, for the getview function:

```
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return mThumbIdToFullSizeId.get(mThumbIds[position]);
}
```

And everything will be much more memory friendly.
I'm giving the checkmark to Muhannad for giving me the link to  http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html which helped alot

Comment: Very Good I am very glad that I gave you a tip but you did every thing , thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. My app always run good without any problem but started crashing with *OutOfMemory* error on devices with Android 4. In particular, it crashes when loading the GalleryView adapter. After reading many pages of the offical documentation (http://android.developer.com) I learned that the memory is used differently from the old version of SO but definitively solved the problem working on the manifest file. I set Android 3.0 as Project Build target, added android:targetSdkVersion="15", added android:largeHeap="true" to the application tag and finally added supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"

Hope this can help you too!

Comment: Thanks! Like I wrote below, I already solved the issue in a different manner, but I'll keep this in mind next time I get into such a problem

Comment: I wonder what are the collateral effects of such settings... I am facing the same problem when loading some bitmaps, and I think I will end creating a different apk for SGS3 or directly setting it as an unsupported device. I prefer to lost some hundreds of users than having hundreds of complains about crashes.

Comment: BTW, I have no problem with Android 4 itself, I have even a Nexus7 with JB and a SGS2 with ICS actual devices, and my game simply works PERFECT on those. So my problem is exclusively with the SGS3.