# delete views that are not visible in gridView

Tags: android, memory, gridview

This is a follow-up question to [android gridview crashes on Galaxy 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999204/android-gridview-crashes-on-galaxy-3)
I fixed some stuff, and now I get the gridView to load. I have many images in the gridView, so I need to scroll down to see al of them. If I scroll down slowly, everything seems to be ok. But if I scroll down fast, the app crashes with OutOfMemory error. So, Iassume that the views that are nolonger visible, take time to be deleted. Is there a fast way to manually delete them and prevent this from happening?
You can see all the gridView code in this
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999204/android-gridview-crashes-on-galaxy-3) (and if you can answer it too, it will be great)

Comment: First, make sure the small thumbnails are really small. second, try generating the bitmaps for all your thumbnails in advance and using setImageBitmap() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because when u scrolling your gridview then getView() method call using adapter.This method is responsible for set image but due to poor performance of server image not make at a time for set in this view thats why outofmemory error occures.

Use this example in your code [Android: Help in adapting ListView adapter with an ImageLoader Class (LazyList)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867894/android-help-in-adapting-listview-adapter-with-an-imageloader-class-lazylist).

Its should help for you.