# How to test an Android app on Samsung Galaxy S3?

Tags: android, testing, samsung-mobile

One of the app I am working on works fine on Samsung Galaxy Ace and Samsung Galaxy Y but a user reported that app crashes on installation in Samsung Galaxy S3.

Now I am wondering how could a app working well one phone crashes on installation on another phone, what could be the reason for such a crash?

Also how could I replicate the behavior of Samsung Galaxy S3 even when I don't have one and I don't intent to buy one (given the cost of the phone)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804619/samsung-galaxy-s3-emulator-settings).You can also create an emulator of samsung galaxy s3

Comment: you can create an emulator for galaxy s3,in for first question you need to give your project version,your min sdk version as well

Comment: @AamirKhan I have given Project Version and minsdk version in Android Manifest, which are 1.0 and 8 respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by AppMobiGurmeet in his comment, you can start by creating an Android emulator with the same characteristics as the Galaxy S3.

This can be enough to solve simple bugs, but there is really nothing like testing on the real device.
As it is impossible for you to test on this phone, I would advise you to implement some crash reporting system in your app, using [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) for example (a really great library for debugging). This way yuo will see the stack of the crash (which is enough in most cases to understand what is going wrong)

Answer (score 2):

> Now I am wondering how could a app working well one phone crashes on
>   installation on another phone, what could be the reason for such a
>   crash?

Do you know what is the exception when it crashes?  There could be so many reasons.

- Different VM max size
- Different screen resolution
- Permissions - are you using specific hardware features/internet/external storage

It is impossible to tell without knowing the exception. If you cannot get the device, you can try to emulate as close to the device as possible. Android emulator allows you all these settings - screen resolution, max VM heap size, RAM size, external storage etc. So get the technical specs of that device and set up your emulator accordingly. Then try to reproduce the problem