# Any Android Emulator?

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, android-emulator, emulation

I currently have a web app and an app on `google play`. What i want to know is, Is there an `emulator` for android galaxy note, s3 google nexus and so on.
Also is there an `emulator` for non iOS or android like windows mobile, blackberry for me to test out my web app and see if it works on them devices with the screen resolutions.

please help.

thanks.

Comment: there are other emulators out there to answer your question

Comment: like what? name some please thanks.

Answer (score 1):

https://app.manymo.com/emulators

Android emulators that:

Start quickly. Run smoothly. Are lightweight.
Match every current OS version & screen size.
Are accessible from your browser.

Answer (score 0):

An [Android emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html) is included in the Android SDK. Using this emulator you can mimic the hardware of a device. OS modifications made by the device vendors are not included in this emulator.

Answer (score 0):

From what i know there is Blackberry Eclipse Plugin ...
Here, a link
https://swdownloads.blackberry.com/Downloads/entry.do?code=060AD92489947D410D897474079C1477

Maybe it helps

Answer (score 0):

The android emulator is included for the SDK, http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at this thread -> [Samsung Galaxy s3 emulator settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804619/samsung-galaxy-s3-emulator-settings) . It mentions configurations to setup the Galaxy SIII emulator, and also other related configurations.

Answer (score 0):

from [Android Studio v2.4](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/04/android-studio-24-preview-4-is-now.html) some of AVD supports Google Play. You can use a native tool because they are much more better than previously